# how to run asp.net code from string variable at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, string, runtime, execute

i have following code in a String variable at run-time

```
<form runat="server">

    <asp:textbox runat="server"
        ID="a1"
        Text="enter text here"
    />
    <asp:button runat="server"
        Text="enter text here"
    />
    <br />
</form>
```

so how can i run it to at run time on a new page by clicking on some button or so?
earliest help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: okay, the above code is created and stored in a String variable at run-time.
now, i want to run that code. how can i do that.

HTML code can be put in LITERAL. and run. 

how can this be donw on ASP>Net counterpart?

Comment: You can't use asp.net controls as string variable. Consider using pure HTML objects or change the concept, like adding specific asp.net controls to something like PlaceHolder.

Comment: i am not using asp.net control as string variable. 

ok lets say, how can i run the asp.net code from certain text file at runtime/?

Comment: Yea... not going to happen, at least not how you're suggesting. Put this code into a user control, and pass the control name as a string instead.

Comment: You have to aware that Visual Studio keeps track of the Controls of a certain UserControl on the ascx.designer.cs, ASP.NET uses it to precompile the pages when they are run on the web server.

Comment: You know, something tells me that you've got a problem that you're trying to solve and going about it in the wrong way.  How about giving us some background into what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned loading from a text file.  I think you should review usercontrols.  It is the preferred method to load asp.net content and controls from an included file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: no, no! the above code is stored in a text file. i want to run it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into a user control, and pass the control name as a string instead.

```
void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //your string
    string controlName = "TempControl_Samples1.ascx.cs";

    // instantiate usercontrol object
    MyControl myControl1 = (MyControl)LoadControl(controlName);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myControl1);
}
```